# How symbols are resolved when linking in dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, linker, shared-libraries

Something I still haven't quite absorbed. Nearly all of my development has involved generating and compiling my code together statically, without the use of linking dynamic libraries (dll or .so).

I understand in this case how the compiler and linker can resolve the symbols as it is stepping through the code.

However, when linking in a dynamic library for example, and the dynamic library has been compiled with a different compiler than the main code, will the symbol names not be different?

For example, I define a structure called RequiredData in my main code as shown below. Imagine that the FuncFromDynamicLib() function is part of a separate dynamic library and it takes this same structure RequiredData as an argument. It means that somewhere in the dynamic library, this structure must be defined again? How can this be resolved at the time of dynamic linking that these structures are the same. What if the data members are different? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct RequiredData
{
    string name;
    int value1;
    int value2;
};

int FuncFromDynamicLib(RequiredData);


int main()
{
    RequiredData data;
    data.name = "test";
    data.value1 = 120;
    data.value2 = 200;

    FuncFromDynamicLib(data);
    return 0;
}


//------------Imagine that this func is Part of dynamic library in another file--------------------
int FuncFromDynamicLib(RequiredData rd)
{
    cout<<rd.name<<endl;
    cout<<rd.value1<<endl;
    cout<<rd.value2<<endl;
}
//------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If the data members are different, your program may crash. You can prevent this by sharing the definitions of your types amongst all pieces of your program (.so's and the main binary). If you change the definition for any reason, you also have to remember to compile both...

Comment: The process used to uniquely identify symbol names in C/C++ is called "name mangling". The Wikipedia page has some useful info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: @DominicDosSantos name mangling is consistent across compilations with the same compiler, though.

Comment: Would the library still link at runtime if the structure names were different. Furthermore, if the data members in the structures were not the same size, would it still link anyways and leave it up to the programmer to know what he is doing?

Answer (score 5):

You are completely right that you cannot in general mix your tools. The process of "linking" is not standardized or specified, and so in general you have to use the same toolchain for the entire process, or indeed one part won't know how the other part called the symbols in the object code.

The problem is in fact worse: it's not just symbol names that must match, but also calling conventions: how to propagate function arguments, return values, exceptions, and how to handle RTTI and dynamic casts.

All these factors are summarized under the term "application binary interface", ABI for short. And the problem you describe can be summarized as "there is no standard ABI".

Several factors make the situation less dire:

- For C code, every major platform as a *de facto* standard ABI which is followed by most tools. Therefore, C code is *in practice* highly portable and interoperable.
- For C++ code, the ABI is much more complex than for C. However, for x86 and x86-64, two major platforms, the Itanium ABI is used on a wide variety of platforms, which creates at least a somewhat interoperable environment.  In particular, that ABI's rules for *name mangling* (i.e. how to represent namespace-qualified names and function overload sets as flat strings) are well-known and have widespread tooling support.

For C++, there are further peculiar concerns. Shipping compiled code to customers is one thing, but another issue is that much of C++ library code lives in headers and gets compiled each time. So the problem is not just that you may be using different compilers, but also *different library implementations*. Internal details of class layout become relevant, because you can't just access vendor A's vector as if it were vendor B's vector. GCC has dubbed this "library ABI".

Comment: If for example the structure defined in the dynamic library had value1 defined as an unsigned 32-bit integer , and an 8-bit signed integer in the main code, will the code still link? I guess however , the same header file with declarations would be used for both the library and the main code right?

Comment: @Engineer999: How can the variable have different types if it's declared by the same header in both translation units?

Comment: If it is not declared by the same header in both translation units i meant

Comment: @Engineer999: Right, then you're in trouble. As I said, C++ does not contain a formal notion of "linking". It does however contain the "one-definition rule", which says that you shall not do what you said, and if you violate that rule, the program is ill-formed, and *no diagnostic is required*. That is, your program is broken, but nobody will tell you. Yes, programming is *that* hard. The conclusions is that you should *always* use headers to declare external entities, and use one and the same header everywhere.

Comment: At compile time of the main program, is the symbol table of the dynamic library checked to make sure that it will link correctly when required, or is it just linked at runtime and that's it? Thanks

Comment: @Engineer999: Linking is not generally diagnosable. Nothing is checked. All that our present-day linkers to is look up symbol names (by string), so the best you can hope for is an unresolved symbol leading to an early error. *Anything* beyond that is *totally* your responsibility. If a symbol exists but means something else, all bets are off.

Comment: @Engineer999: For example, if you treat an `int` like a `long int` because you declared the variable as one type here and as the other there, nothing will tell you that and your program might just blow up.